# Pass Fragment Class as a parameter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm not sure if this is doable, but I'm trying to pass a Fragment Class as a parameter so that I can have a centralized class with ONE method for multiple other classes.

Here is the method that I'm trying to write but I'm missing the "Fragment Class argument" in the method:

```
public void onStartFragment(??? ???, Fragment fragment, int containerViewId) {


    fragment = (???) getChildFragmentManager().
            findFragmentByTag(???.class.getName());

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = ???.newInstance();
    }
    FragmentTransaction childFragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    childFragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId,
            fragment, ???.class.getName())
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

My Goal is to have one method that can be used to start any fragment.

Comment: `???.newInstance()` ... That one will be difficult because `???.class` will almost always be just `Fragment` if you are planning on using generics

Comment: Also, `fragment = ` is overriding `Fragment fragment`, so certainly this isn't what you want?

Comment: Right I'm trying to have `???.newInstance()` to be the fragment class that was passed in instead of `Fragment` class.

Comment: but if I have a `fragment` instance, I can always typecast it to the `Fragment Class` I'm passing in if I'm obtaining that needed parameter, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to use the class name as a tag (and maybe a backstack entry name), just pass the class name, not the fragment.

Then use `Fragment.instantiate(context, className)` to have an instance of your class.

```
public void onStartFragment(String className, int containerViewId) {

    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(className);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(context, className);
        // fragment is a className instance now
    }

    manager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(containerViewId, fragment, className)
               .addToBackStack(className)
               .commit();
}
```

The method can be refined further depending on your desired behaviour, but you got the point. You can also pass a `Class<? extends Fragment>` if you wish.

Comment: This works like a charm ! Just added some more parameters to the separate method ! I added some more lines to complete what you started in a separate answer. Great answer, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Method overloading might help you here

```
public void onStartFragment(FragmentManger manager, Fragment fragment, String tag, int containerViewId) {

    // could check for tag here

    manager
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(containerViewId, fragment, tag)
        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
}

public void onStartFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag, int containerViewId) {
    onStartFragment(
        getFragmentManager() // Or child, if you are in a Fragment already
        fragment, tag, containerViewId);
}

public void onStartFragment(Fragment fragment, int containerViewId) {
    onStartFragment(fragment, null, containerViewId);
}
```

Place whereever you need to call those methods,

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
onStartFragment(frag, frag.class.getName(), R.id.container); // for example
```

In other words, this should probably be handled externally of that method since I'm not sure you can reliably get `???.class.getName()`

```
fragment = (???) getChildFragmentManager().
        findFragmentByTag(???.class.getName());

if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = ???.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think your answer is going to solve my question. I'm already passing the parameters that I need but the only missing one is the **Fragment class parameter**. So far, I'm thinking that I might need to use the `Object` **class**, since it superclasses the java **class**, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean between `Fragment` and "Fragment class"

Comment: You are just needing a string tag, which can be **anything**. It does not need to be the Fragment class name

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on @natario answer,  I used the start fragment method in a separate class:

`public class FragmentSeparateClass extends Fragment {`

```
public void onStartFragment(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager, String className, int containerViewId) {

    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(className);

    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(context, className);
    }
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(containerViewId, fragment, className)
            .addToBackStack(className)
            .commit();
}
```

`}`

Then I used the method in the needed **Fragment classes**, for instance:

```
           fragmentSeperateCLass.onStartFragment(getContext(), getChildFragmentManager(), FirstChildFragment.class.getName(),
                    R.id.firstChildFragmentLayout);
        }
```